# Difference between sum of squares and squares of sum in two sequences $a_i \leq b_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I am trying to get a result from a equation. In particular I want to show that the value is greater or equal to zero.

$$
    =C \cdot  ((d_{[k]}^2 \cdot  (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2) + a^2_{[k]}\cdot  \\
     (2(a_{[k]}\cdot d_{[k]})) - a^2_{[k]}\cdot (d_1^2 + \dots + d_k^2) - 2a_{[k]}d_{[k]}\cdot  (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2) ) \\
    =C \cdot  ((2\cdot a_{[k]}\cdot d_{[k]} \cdot  (a^2_{[k]} - (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2))) +\\
    (d_{[k]}^2 \cdot  (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2) - a^2_{[k]}\cdot (d_1^2 + \dots + d_k^2)))\\
$$

I know for sure that $\forall i, 0 \leq d_i \leq a_i$ and that $d_{[k]} < a_{[k]}$

I am simplifying $d_{[k]} = \sum_{i=1}^kd_i$

The first parentheses of the second equation is definitely greater than zero and C is greater than zero. My trouble is with the second parentheses: I am not even sure it is true that is greater than zero (let alone prove that). What I see is that both parts of the subtraction are either a sum of squares or a square of sums.

I understand this has might have been answered in the past, but I could not find an answer as I am not sure if it has a special name.

Is it true that this equation has value greater than zero? If so, I would appreciate help seeing it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:
$$
    \ge C * (2*a_{[k]}*d * (a^2_{[k]} - (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2)) + (d^2 * (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2) - a^2_{[k]}*d^2) \\
    \ge C * (2*d^2 * (a^2_{[k]} - (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2)) + (d^2 * ((a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2) - a^2_{[k]})) \\
    \ge C * (2*d^2 * (a^2_{[k]} - (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2)) - (d^2 * (a^2_{[k]}) - (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2)) \\
    \ge C * (d^2 * (a^2_{[k]} - (a_1^2 + \dots + a_k^2))) > 0\\
$$

I wonder if I should remove this question...